# IP Address? - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, user-interface

How would I make a GUI program that displays your Ip address with a click of a button? Please, no difficult explanations, I just started Cocoa not long ago.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: He wants to do this on a Mac, where he doesn't have VB.

Comment: Yea I've done the IP thing in Visual Basic, but I wanna try doing it in Cocoa

Comment: let me get that for you... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Answer (score 9):

You can get IP address through two ways:

1- if you want to get the local ip address on the current used netwrok, you can use the following method to retrive it:

```
-(NSString *)getIPAddress
{
    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0)
    {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL)
        {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }

    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;
}
```

2- if you want to get the external IP address then you need to use the following method:

```
-(NSString*)getIP
{
    NSUInteger  an_Integer;
    NSArray * ipItemsArray;
    NSString *externalIP;

    NSURL *iPURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dyndns.org/cgi-bin/check_ip.cgi"];

    if (iPURL) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *theIpHtml = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:iPURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            NSScanner *theScanner;
            NSString *text = nil;

            theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:theIpHtml];

            while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

                // find start of tag
                [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ;

                // find end of tag
                [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

                // replace the found tag with a space
                //(you can filter multi-spaces out later if you wish)
                theIpHtml = [theIpHtml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
                             [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text]
                                                                 withString:@" "] ;
                ipItemsArray =[theIpHtml  componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
                an_Integer=[ipItemsArray indexOfObject:@"Address:"];
                externalIP =[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:  ++an_Integer];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@",externalIP);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Oops... g %d, %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
    return externalIP;
}
```

Comment: You should only call `freeifaddrs()` if `getifaddrs()` succeeded.

Answer (score 7):

For determining the IP address, I found 
[this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2002/Apr/msg01308.html).

As for making it into a Cocoa app, add an `NSTextField` (label) to your main window in Interface Builder, put in a button, add in an application controller (a subclass of `NSObject` that you make), put in the outlet and the action, do the proper connenctions, and in the "get IP" method, put in that code and set the value for the label's `stringValue`.

You can use `[[NSHost currentHost] address]`, but it won't always display what you like.  On my system, for example, it gives my IPv6 address.

**EDIT:**  On my system, `[[[NSHost currentHost] addresses] objectAtIndex:0]` has my IPv4 address.

Comment: for me it's not the first object, it's the last. Also, rather than using objectAtIndex, I suggest "lastObject": [[[NSHost currentHost] addresses] lastObject]

Comment: For me it is the second index out of 5. Perhaps some validation is needed if you are specifically looking for an IPv4 or IPv6 adress.

Answer (score 4):

`[[NSHost currentHost] addresses]` will get you an array of IPs. Read the [documentation for NSHost](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/).

As for displaying that in a GUI, I recommend getting Aaron Hillegass' book Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X, or any Cocoa beginners book should teach that.

Comment: Is NSHost consistent in the ordering of the addresses?  I've read some people saying it isn't, but that was talking about just plain address, not addresses.  I've never had occasion to use NSHost.

Comment: Well, an array does maintain order, vs a dictionary.. I couldn't really say how reliable it is though.

Comment: Alright.  What I meant was, does it always go IPv6, IPv4, link local, IPv4 loopback, IPv6 loopback?

Comment: Hmm.. it seems like if you have IPv6 enabled, it'll show that first, then IPv4.

Otherwise I think it follows the sequence of your system preferences -> network interfaces list.

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote this, may need some work but seems to work well on my machine...

```
- (NSString *)getLocalIPAddress
{
    NSArray *ipAddresses = [[NSHost currentHost] addresses];
    NSArray *sortedIPAddresses = [ipAddresses sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormatter.allowsFloats = NO;

    for (NSString *potentialIPAddress in sortedIPAddresses)
    {
        if ([potentialIPAddress isEqualToString:@"127.0.0.1"]) {
            continue;
        }

        NSArray *ipParts = [potentialIPAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

        BOOL isMatch = YES;

        for (NSString *ipPart in ipParts) {
            if (![numberFormatter numberFromString:ipPart]) {
                isMatch = NO;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isMatch) {
            return potentialIPAddress;
        }
    }

    // No IP found
    return @"?.?.?.?";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `hostWithName:` method with current host name. This will return only single local IPv4 and IPv6 IP, which we can filter easily.

We can get the current system host name using `[[NSHost currentHost] name]`.

```
+(NSString *)getLocalIPAddress{
    NSArray *ipAddresses = [[NSHost hostWithName:[[NSHost currentHost] name]] addresses];
    for (NSString *ipAddress in ipAddresses) {
        if ([ipAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@"."].count == 4) {
            return ipAddress;
        }
    }
    return @"Not Connected.";
}
```

So, this will solve all the problems mentions in comments of other answers. Also, this significantly work more faster than other solution mention here.