# How to changing an iOS app icon and background on behalf of App Store location?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am making an iOS app for a company which has offices in different countries(England, France, Germany). Background colors and images for every country office will be different but functionality will be same. App name will be same as well. I want to make app available for specific country. For example Germany office app should only be available in Germany app store. Right now i am making 3 different apps. One for each country office. Problem is that when i make an update then i have to do that in all those 3 apps. Is there any way to do all above things using one app. So when i do an update then i just update one app. Or is there any way to make one app available in only England, Germany and France appStore and then when Germany office tries to download then it shows their background and images. I do not want to give them an option in app to choose their country. Is there anyways to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes and no. You can't change the App icon. It's in the app bundle which is readonly.
It is also not possible to check from which appstore the app is downloaded, so you will have to ask the user or use GPS.

The app colour scheme you will be able to change, just as the language. You can use iOS own localization for this, but it will then be depended on the system language.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. There are two main ways to do that:

1. Using device settings (Language):
   You cannot change app Icon only according to Locale (device language settings). But, With this method you could get different graphics to every language and separate artwork for each language (buttons, Screenshots, backgrounds, texts and every other thing you can think of). On your case that could be nice but it isn't perfect (it would be really easy to implement though).
2. Understand where the user is:
   You can figure out where the user is, Problem with that is user can use the Germany App Store while being in France. But I assume that if he is in France he would like to see the service that relevant to Frace origin.
   You can do that through GPS, But that would make the app request permission to location services, Or you can check where he is from the IP he is using (see how to get external IP here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13308528/1071887). When you has his external IP you could transfer it to approx. location through lots of services. After you get where he is you can arrange the relevant artwork.

I assume what do you really need is a mix of both, Use Localisation to support all those 3 languages and use the location to support the appropriate graphics.

If you do think you could use only 3 apps for this propose, You should use 3 targets on same project. This way it would be pretty easy to maintain.

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no (current) way to have different icons other than multiple different apps in the iOS App Store.